# Undefined method in rake file

Tags: ruby, symfony, capistrano, capistrano3

I get error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `symfony_console'
```

in my task defined in rake file (lib/capistrano/tasks/my_tasks.rake)

```
task :migrate do
  on roles(:all) do
    symfony_console('doctrine:migrations:migrate', '--no-interaction')
  end
end
```

*symfony_console* method provided by *capistrano/symfony* extension. Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/composer'
require 'capistrano/symfony'
```

What i am doing wrong?

**Updated:**
Problem may be related to roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to old versions of capistrano/symfony

Comment: Can you please explain how you updated `capistrano/symfony`?

Answer (score 2):

If you given the whole Capfile, you are missing the `capistrano/symfony`.

Change it like this :

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/composer'
require 'capistrano/symfony'
```

Make sure you have correctly installed gems `capistrano` and 
`capistrano-symfony`, otherwise follow [this step](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony#installation).

I never used this feature (`symfony_console(...)`) but it should works.

**EDIT**

Your should write your task in your `deploy.rb`.

**EDIT2**

If you doesn't yet, try to set a namespace for your task like this :

```
namespace :deploy do
  before 'updated', 'schemadb'
  task :migrate do
    on roles(:all) do
      symfony_console('doctrine:migrations:migrate', '--no-interaction')
    end
  end
end
```

If it doesn't work, try to change the task body to :

```
on roles(:all) do
  invoke 'symfony:console', 'doctrine:migrations:migrate', '--no-interaction'
end
```

This is what I use.

Comment: Did you tried to move the task from your `my_tasks.rake` directly in your `deploy.rb` ?

Comment: Not yet. Also, current configuration works locally, and fail on deploy server. Now i think about roles, can you comment it? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how roles can cause this. Also, `on roles(':all')` works well for me, but for a task that is defined in my `deploy. rb` às part of the `deploy` namespace. Look at my last edit, maybe adding the namespace could fix it. Otherwise, the last solution (avoiding `symfony_console()`) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue with capistrano-symfony version 1.0.0.rc3. It's looks like `https://github.com/capistrano/symfony/blob/master/lib/capistrano/dsl/symfony.rb` is not imported/used.

I'm definitely not a Ruby expert, but I'm very curious how to debug this...